# Redshift - What is CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE command for?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

When I run CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA, I automatically see the tables inside that schema.
Recently, I've been watching some tutorial videos where CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE is run after CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA.  What's the point of CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA already links to those tables?

Answer (score 0):

External schema can be of various types. One can create external schemas from Glue Data Catalog, another Redshift local database, or a remote Postgres or MySQL DB, etc.

Some of these are read-only. Both in terms of data and metadata. i.e. One cannot insert a new record in any of the tables and one cannot create another table in the schema. The second and third types mentioned above fall into this category.

On the other hand, a schema created from Glue Catalog is read-only in terms of data. But one can add new tables to it. To create tables on top of files in this schema, we need the `CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA` statement.

You can either choose to create these tables through Redshift or you can create them through Athena or Glue Crawlers etc.